# How to get the HtmlPage object after I set the input value by code. (java webparser)

Tags: java, input, htmlunit

I use java to crawl a webpage.

I imported `com.gargoylesoftware.html` unit in my project and I can get the web page.

There is an input in the webpage. When I enter a key word in the input and press the "Enter" key, part of the webpage is refreshed. There is no submit button. So how can I get the refreshed webpage in my java code?

Here is my code:

```
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
client.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

HtmlPage page = client.getPage(url);
HtmlInput termInput = (HtmlInput) page.getByXPath("/html/body/div[2]/div/main/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/input").get(0);
termInput.setAttribute("value", "Annual Report");
saveFile(this.getFilePath(""), page.asXml());
```

---

I save the webpage as a file in my computer. I can open it in the browser. And I can see the value I set in the input but the content isn't refreshed.

There isn't a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

In order to refresh the page by pressing enter you need to enter the escape sequence for enter into the input.

You do this by typing \n into the input like such:

```
termInput.type("\n");
```